# timeshift path is set to /tmp/.. instead of /timeshift/

Tags: 18.04, snapshot, timeshift

after I restored my ubuntu using timeshift, I noticed that the gui does not show any of my snapshots. It seems that timeshift is somehow linked to /tmp folder instead of /timeshift. Is there any way to change the path that timeshift refers to?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpFDH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two potential solutions to this:

1. Run the setup wizard. The snapshot storage location is set to /timeshift on the device you choose.
2. Uninstall and reinstall TimeShift. I had a similar issue recently and in my case something had updated with the result that TimeShift could not read the device on which the snapshots were kept. This resolved the issue and my snapshot history was still intact.

Good luck